# objc_getClassList returning incorrect number of classes found?

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I have some code like this:

```
int numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
...
Class * classes = malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. When it fails, I see that the value of `numClasses` return by the second call is different to the first. For example, in the project the first call returns 1534. Sometimes the second returns 1534 as well and everything works fine. but sometimes it returns 1536 and the program crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS because it has not allocated enough memory.

My question is why would `objc_getClassList` be returning two different numbers (sometimes!) ????

Comment: Are you later in the code using the new value of `numClasses` when indexing `classes`? What is happening in the `...` lines? Are you (for example) loading any bundles?

Comment: I think that the number of classes has simply grown between the first and the second call. Surround it with try {} catch {} and increase the number if it fails.

Comment: I'm thinking that as you guys say, more stuff is being loaded. The "..." really doesn't include much more that some NSLogs and stuff. After this code I then loop over the results which is why I'm getting the crash. It looks like Apple's API sample code is not that great so at the moment I'm taking the approach of ignoring the second returned value and just using the first for the loop. This appears to have stopped the crashes, but I'm not sure of the side effects.

Comment: Facing the same issue, would love to hear what people did to get around this. My workaround is the same, to simply ignore the second `numClasses` returned as I've only allocated enough size for the first attempt, but it feels wrong.